# how to build records on after_create using external data

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My account model

```
has_many :articles
after_create :generate_default_articles
def generate_default_articles
  article = articles.build(:title => 'User guide', :content => 'This is fake content', :author => 'Admin')
  article.save
  true
end
```

This works. However, I need `content` to be more complex and longer than a few words, i.e. a simple html page. So I would like to put that content in an external file. How do I do this ? What format should I use for that file ?

### Edit after answer

Below is my final code using rii's answer and I18n for the title:

```
def generate_default_articles
  content1 = File.open("#{Rails.root}/public/default_article_1_content.txt", "r+") {|f| f.read}
  article1 = articles.build(:title => I18n.t('article1_title'), :content => content1, :author => 'Admin')
  article1.save
  true
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several options here. If the `content` attribute is a text field you can store all the text content in there by opening a file you've stored in your system. The other option you have is using a gem like carrier_wave or paper_clip and store the reference to the file  using the gem: https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave

https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip

The gem route is probably the most flexible way.

Now, how do you open a file in Ruby? Well, the File class is your friend:

```
content = File.open("your_file.txt", "r+")
file.close
```

As far as the file type, if it's just text you are storing, then have it be a .txt or maybe even an .html file. You can access your files path by doing something like so:

```
file = "#{RAILS_ROOT}/public/html_file/html_file1.html"
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: I found a third way using I18n which I am using for the `title` attribute. For the `content`attribute I decided to go with the simple 'File.open' that you suggested.